# Как выделить память под массив внутри функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели, память

В инте объявляю сам массив

```
int main() {
    int mas, n;
    input(mas, &n);
    free(mas);
}
```

Но собственно так как он без указания размера, это не правильно. В функции надо выделить под него память, в зависимости от введенного n.

```
void input(int *a, int *n) {
    char temp;
    if ((scanf("%d%c", n, &temp) == 1) || (temp == '\n')) {
        a = (int*)malloc((*n) * sizeof(int));
```

Как это сделать правильно? Чтобы массив вернулся в инт.

Answer (score 6):

Вообще-то в `int` массив никак не вернуть, потому что массив — это по сути указатель на первый элемент, а размеры `int` и указателя могут и не совпадать.

Далее, при передаче аргумента в функцию по значению создается копия, так что даже если бы ваш `input` работал, переданная переменная-указатель не изменялась бы. Странно, что при этом `n` вы передаете правильно...

И — по мелочи — если у вас в самом деле С, то в `= (int*)malloc` приведение `(int*)` не нужно.

Можно [так](https://ideone.com/trrFBD):

```
int* input(int *n) 
{
    if (scanf("%d", n) == 1) 
    {
        return malloc((*n) * sizeof(int));
    }
    else return NULL;
}
int main() {
    int *mas, n;
    mas = input(&n);
    free(mas);
}
```

Comment: `if (mas)` нужен?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, это С, не С++, и `free`, в отличие от `delete`, такую проверку не выполняет.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free : "If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing."

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Интересно бы уточнить, с какого это стандарта (С99?), потому как точно помню, что раньше это требовалось, когда-то сам на такое налетел и с тех пор в голову вбито накрепко... OK, убираю.